Algorithms by Dasgupta-Papadimitriou-Vazirani Prologue confusion

We will see in Chapter 1 that the addition of two n-bit numbers takes time roughly proportional to n; this is not too hard to understand if you think back to the gradeschool procedure for addition, which works on one digit at a time. Thus fib1, which performs about Fn additions, actually uses a number of basic steps roughly proportional to nFn. Likewise, the number of steps taken by fib2 is proportional to n^2, still polynomial in n and therefore exponentially superior to fib1. This correction to the running time analysis does not diminish our breakthrough.

I'm confused on how we know fib1, which is the recursive fibonacci algorithm, performs about Fn additions. Kindly if someone could help explain.
Also, now that I looked into it, in Rosen's Discrete Math book they very briefly (like 1 sentence lol) mention that the number of additions is $F_{n+1} - 1$ (leaving as an exercise for the reader) instead of $F_{n}$. I think I did the strong induction part correctly for the $F_{n+1} - 1$, but not sure how we can approximate to $F_{n}$. Additionally, I was looking more for a derivation rather than just inductive verification.

For all $n\ge 2$,
$$F_n \le F_{n+1}-1\le F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}\le F_n+F_n=2F_n.$$
This shows that $F_n$ close to $F_{n+1}-1$, in the sense that they differ by at most a constant factor. This is what the authors mean when they say "about" $F_n$, since constant factors like this aren't worth keeping track of.
To prove $F_{n+1}-1\ge F_n$, note $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$. Since $F_{n-1}\ge 1$ whenever $n\ge 2$, we conclude $F_{n+1}\ge F_n+1$.

You also said you wanted some more intuition on why fib1 takes $F_{n+1}-1$ additions.
I assume that the code for fib1 looks like this. I use the notation x <- e to mean "set the value of the variable x to be the output of expression e".
Algorithm fib1
Input:  nonnegative integer n

if n equals 0:
    output 0
if n equal 1:
    output 1
else:
    a <- fib1(n-1)
    b <- fib1(n-2)
    c <- a + b
    output c

Let $T(n)$ be the number of additions it takes to compute fib1(n). In order to set the value of a equal to fib1(n-1), we know it recursively takes $T(n-1)$ additions. Similarly, b <- fib1(n-2) takes $T(n-2)$ additions. Finally, c <- a + b takes one addition. Therefore, we get the recursion
$$
T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1
$$
So, how does this lead to $T(n)=F_{n+1}-1$? As far as I know, the best way to discover $F_{n+1}-1$ is to use the recurrence to start computing the list $T(1),T(2),T(3),\dots$, until a pattern emerges. Then you prove that pattern by induction on $n$ (as you have already done).

Sorry I'm having a hard time proving by induction that for all n >= 2 $F_{n} \leq F_{n+1} - 1$. Kindly please help.

So when you say "to start computing T(1), T(2), T(3), ..., until a pattern emerges. Then you prove that pattern (as you have already done)". Are you saying prove by induction?

To your first comment, see edit. To your second comment, yes I mean by induction. When I said "as you have already done", I was referring to the part of your answer when you said "I think I did the strong induction part correctly for the $F_{n+1}-1$".

Thank you so much! This very much helped me! Just 1 more questions though  : is there a way to derive by counting it out that # additions for $F_{n}$ is $F_{n+1} -1$ rather than just verifying by induction?
